# Possibility of bounding $\sum_{n=0}^N |a_n|$ from above by $\sup_{z\in (0,1)} |\sum_{1\leq n\leq N} (1+z+\ldots+z^{n-1}) a_n|$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, inequality

Assume that $a = (a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_N)$ where $N \in \mathbb{N}_+$ is fixed belongs to the space $$V = \left\{a \in (-1,1)^{N+1} : a\neq {\bf 0},~~ \sum_{n=0}^N a_n = 0,~~a_N = 0\right\}$$ I am wondering if it is possible to bound $\sum_{n=0}^N |a_n|$ (or $\max_{0\leq n\leq N} |a_n|$ since $N$ is finite and fixed) by some constant multiple of $\sup_{z\in (0,1)} |\sum_{1\leq n\leq N} (1+z+\ldots+z^{n-1}) a_n|$ (or of some polynomial functions of $\sup_{z\in (0,1)} |\sum_{1\leq n\leq N} (1+z+\ldots+z^{n-1}) a_n|$ ? Any help or suggestions are greatly welcomed!

Comment: No: it is quite possible that $a_0=\sum_{n=0}^N na_n = 0$ while $\sum_{n=0}^N a_n$ can be arbitrarily large, which is enough to show that there is no bound of any shape in terms of just those two parameters.

Comment: @GregMartin I forgot to mention that $a \neq {\bf 0}$. I have modified the post accordingly.

Comment: The question has now been changed significantly.

Comment: @GregMartin Yes, as I originally thought that it suffices to consider only the extreme cases corresponding to $z = 0$ and $z= 1$. I do apologize for that.

Comment: This is similar to the "power sum method" that most often has Turán's name attached to it. You might be able to look into that and derive an adequate inequality for your purposes.

Comment: @GregMartin Thank you very much for pointing out it. I will definitely look into it to see if they are helpful or not!

Comment: Is $a_N=0$ really necessary?

Comment: @SungjinKim Here actually $a_n$ is a difference of two cumulative distribution functions  , i.e., $a_n = F_n - G_n$ for $0\leq n\leq N$. As $F_N = 1 = G_N$, this leads to the constraint that $a_N = 0$ (as you pointed out, this is not a big constraint).

Comment: @GregMartin I dug into the Turan's power sum method but this is not quite the same type of problem as this post is trying to describe...

Comment: Perhaps not, although notice that
$$
\sum_{1\le n\le N} (1+z+\cdots+z^{n-1})a_n = \frac1{1-z}\biggl( \sum_{1\le n\le N} a_n - \sum_{1\le n\le N} a_nz^n \biggr)
$$
and the latter sum is more directly power-sum-method-related....

Comment: @GregMartin I agree with this elementary observation, but this is a difference of two sums (of distinct nature) and Turan's method cannot be adapted easily to this setting in my opinion...

Comment: @GregMartin Also, the problem at hand resembles some sort of "sum of powers" and not "power sum" to be honest

Comment: Small correction - it is correct to write $a\in \{-1,1\}^{N+1}$ and not $a\in (-1,1)^{N+1}$.

Comment: @K.defaoite Hi, the "correction" is wrong. Each element of $a$ belongs to $(-1,1)$ and it is not "binary"!

Comment: @FeiCao I am sorry, I misunderstood. It was late and I was tired.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course, the constant exists, let

$$\mu : \begin{aligned}
\mathbb R^{N} &\to [0, \infty)\\
\boldsymbol{a} &\mapsto \sup\limits_{z\in (0,1)}\left|\sum_{n=1}^N a_n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} z^k\right|
\end{aligned}$$

> **Claim 1**: $\mu$ is a norm on $\mathbb R^N$.

*Proof*: It is clear that $\mu$ is nonnegative and satisfies Absolute homogeneity.

- **Positive definiteness**: if $\mu(\boldsymbol{a}) = 0$ then for all $z\in (0, 1)$, $$\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \left(\sum_{n=k+1}^{N} a_n\right)z^k = \sum_{n=1}^N a_n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} z^k = 0$$ this implies that $$\sum_{n=k+1}^N a_n = 0$$ for all $0\le k\le N-1$. So $a_N = 0$ and for $k = 1,\ldots,N-1$, $$a_k  = \sum_{n=k}^{N}a_n - \sum_{n=k+1}^N a_n  = 0$$ this finally proves that $\boldsymbol{a} = 0$.
- **Triangle inequality**: let $\boldsymbol{a}$ and $\boldsymbol{b}$ in $\mathbb R^N$, since for all $z\in (0, 1)$, $$\left|\sum_{n=1}^{N} \left(a_n + b_n\right) \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} z^k\right| = \left|\sum_{n=1}^{N} a_n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} z^k + \sum_{n=1}^{N} b_n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} z^k\right| \le \left|\sum_{n=1}^{N} a_n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} z^k\right| + \left|\sum_{n=1}^{N} b_n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} z^k\right|$$ then $$\mu\left(\boldsymbol{a} + \boldsymbol{b}\right) \le \mu(\boldsymbol{a}) + \mu(\boldsymbol{b}).$$

Since all norms are equivalent there is a constant $C$ such that for all $\boldsymbol{a} \in \mathbb R^N$

$$\sum_{n=1}^N \left|a_n\right| \le C\mu(\boldsymbol{a}).$$

---

Now let $\boldsymbol{a} \in \mathbb R^{N+1}$ such  that $\sum_{n=0}^N a_n = 0$ then,

$$\sum_{n=0}^N \left|a_n \right| \le 2\sum_{n=1}^N \left|a_n\right| \le 2C \mu\left(\boldsymbol{a}\right)$$

Comment: I am surprised that this question looks so simple in your mind. But no, your argument is wrong. My $a$ belongs to $\mathbb{R}^{N+1}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ and there is no way that the $\sup_{z\in (0,1)} \ldots$ is actually a norm on $\mathbb{R}^{N+1}$

Comment: You can forget about the $a_0$ because it is related to other coefficients let me update my answer to explain to you that it works.

Comment: I updated my answer you can look  at it now.

Comment: It is not clear at all that $\mu(a)$ satisfies the triangle inequality (and I believe it is wrong)

Comment: I added proof for the triangle inequality. Now you can believe it is right.

Comment: Hi Kroki, I start to be convinced... The key observation that "all norms on finite dimensional Euclidean spaces are equivalent" seems to be "a big weapon"...; I will wait in case other people might have issues regarding your answer.

Comment: Would you mind me citing this answer in a paper I am going to write since I will need the conclusion of my original post ?  Thank you !

Comment: I don't mind at all. You can replicate the proof in the paper.

Comment: Thank you! Although the really interesting case is when $N \to \infty$, I am fine with a positive answer in the simpler case (even though the constant involved might blow up to infinity as $N \to \infty$)

Comment: The constant will definitively blow up as $N\to\infty$.